# Errors after creating partitions during Fedora 20 installation

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation, boot-loader

I made drives like this:

```
/       10GB
/home   37GB
swap     8GB
```

But there is an error:

```
you have not created a bootloader stage1 target device.
you have not created a bootable partition.
```

What should I do?

Comment: With the changes you made per the one answer would you mind updating your Q to show what you're currently have setup now? thanks.

Comment: What exactly have you done in the installer? It's important to be precise. Tell us the exact title of the screen you're at, what buttons you pressed on the previous screens, etc.

Comment: how did you solve this? I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I myself solved this problem, I use the Fedora 20 live `disk` application to change disk partitions and after this it works. Without creating `/boot` or something like that.

Comment: Do you have more details, I am not sure I could reproduce that solution and that could help @ian out who commented on your question.

Comment: You need 2 primitive partition and this error is for that.One for / partition and another for create extended partition for your swap partition .and if you have any other free extended space for swap (for made a logical partition),one primitive partition is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Create a /boot partition, 500 MB would be more than enough, and format it as ext3.

Comment: I create it ,but make no defference.

Comment: Mark it bootable in fdisk.

Comment: There's no need to have a separate `/boot` partition unless you're using a partitioning scheme that the bootloader can't read (e.g. an encrypted root partition). It wouldn't help anyway: what needs to be done here is arrange for the partition containing `/boot` to be bootable (whether it's `/` or `/boot`).